# PHP under Laragon - SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, laragon

I am using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) 4.0.16 on Windows 10 to develop in PHP.

I enabled SSL using the Laragon tool to do so:

[image]

Also added laragon.crt to the Trust Store.

[image]

I can access my test project at `https://project.test` correctly.

But, there is an issue:

> Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
> Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

I have been reading that the way to fix such issue is to set *curl.cainfo* and *openssl.cafile* in the PHP ini configuration file.

I did so, in the Laragon global *php.ini* located at `C:\laragon\bin\php\php-xxx\php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile = "C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

But after restarting Laragon, the php warning persists.

What else can I do to track down the problem and fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [command line tool `openssl` to verify certificates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/how-can-i-verify-ssl-certificates-on-the-command-line).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried figuring that issue out a couple of hours.
All the solutions i found stated the following things:

- Download the cacert from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and replace the one in laragon/etc/ssl/
- set the openssl.cafile in php.ini to laragon\etc\ssl\laragon.crt (e.g. openssl.cafile= "C:\laragon\etc\ssl\laragon.crt")

Didn't helpt at all. The thing that actually worked was to switch to php 7.3 (my code wasn't capable of running 7.4 and i ran into different errors there).
The reason why seems to be that for php 7.2.19 the php_openssl.dll has the version 1.1.1b and the php_openssl.dll for version 7.3 and up has the version 1.1.1k.

That finally fixed the issue. I hope that helps someone couple of hours of madness. I'm not sure if this can occur again in future versions of php :)

Comment: Downloading and replacing the Laragon cacert.pem worked for me.